# Utilizar um mapa customizado

Tags: android, maps

Estou tentando criar um mapa a partir de uma imagem *.png* que eu tenho.
Algo como o aplicativo do Beto Carreiro.

Alguém sabe alguma *lib* que eu consiga fazer isso? 
Tentei utilizar a `Mappwidget` e a `TileView` sem sucesso